# How to only execute code on a specific route?

Tags: vue.js

I have number of inputs in a form:

```html
<input type="text" @change="clearInput($event, titleError)" ref="bookTitle">
<span ref="titleError"></span>

<input type="text" @change="clearInput($event, authorError)">
<span id="author-error" class="text-danger errors"></span>
```

I use the function below to handle change:

```js
const titleError = ref(null)
const authorError = ref(null)

function clearInput(e, inputError) {
    e.target.classList.remove('is-invalid')
    inputError.innerText = ''
}
```

I get an error when going back while focusing on one of the inputs: `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')`.

[I press back while focusing on title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxPay.png)

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I4le.png)

I tried to use template refs and check if input exists, and it worked:

```js
const bookTitle = ref(null)
function clearInput(e, inputError) {
    if (bookTitle.value) { // Only testing with title
        e.target.classList.remove('is-invalid')
        inputError.innerText = ''
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to prevent this error from happening considering how much code I have to write (much cleaner code)?

Comment: Don't use dom directly without a good reason in vue.

Comment: You don't provide code that reproduces the problem. But from what you added, it is strange to see the error `Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerText')`, because it should be another: `Uncaught ReferenceError: inputError is not defined` ))